# How to calculate the size of an Erlang process in memory?

Tags: process, erlang

I have a 'worker' process which I am going to assign to a job. Before I spawn hundreds of processes of this type I would like to know the memory consumption figures for it.

I know that I should sum all the elements which are stored in the process' loop data (all tuples, atoms, lists, etc) and the actual process memory footprint.

As I understand, before doing that I have to know the actual size of a {tuple|atom|list|process} itself.

**Given a certain data structure which is stored in the process' memory how can I calculate the overall size of the process in memory?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`erlang:process_info/2` will give you the amount of memory, in bytes, that a process occupies. For example:

```
1> erlang:process_info(whereis(code_server), memory).
{memory,284208}
```

Note that binaries are not included since they are not located in the process heap. Those you have to count the size of manually.

Comment: just wanted to add [a useful link to docs](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html), where they calculate number of words per process: `Bytes div erlang:system_info(wordsize).`

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [Erlang Efficiency Guide on Memory](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html#id68294)?